# recursion, how branch exploration works?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

so, I kinda know how recursion works, to simplify, a function call itself until a condition is met. Now, I am reading [eloquentJavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_2m+jfYF6Yv), its great. It explain recursion with the following example:

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
             find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(13));
// result: (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)
```

Now this function with the help of recursion find out how, starting from 1, you can obtain a number only by multiplying by three or adding 5, if possible. If not it returns null, if you match the number it will print the passages (history),thus exiting the recursion.

What I can't understand is how can it guess the sequence of adding and multiplying and do the branching thing. The find function return null if the number more than target, return history if equal, try to add 5 calling itself, or multiplying by 3 also by calling itself. So it shouldn't be able to guess the path to 13, instead it works.

Javascript wise, how is this possible?

Here is how it explains it

To better understand how this function produces the effect we’re looking for, let’s look at all the calls to find that are made when searching for a solution for the number 13.

```
  find(6, "(1 + 5)")
    find(11, "((1 + 5) + 5)")
      find(16, "(((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)")
        too big
      find(33, "(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3)")
        too big
    find(18, "((1 + 5) * 3)")
      too big
  find(3, "(1 * 3)")
    find(8, "((1 * 3) + 5)")
      find(13, "(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)")
        found!
```

How can it goes back? Please help me

Comment: *"How can it goes back?"*: it goes back by returning `null`. Then the caller will proceed with the `||` operator, and try the alternative. If that also comes back with `null`, it will return that same value itself (because `null || null === null`)

Comment: The operands of the comparison are evaluated one by one (recursively in this case), from left to right. and the `return` keyword makes it "*go back*".

Answer (score 0):

What may be missing in your knowledge is how the memory stack is handled during the recursions. Let's do it step by step.

Calling

```
find(1, "1")
```

Those variables are in memory stack #0:

- `current` is `1`
- `history` is `"1"`
- `target` is `13`

Makes:

```
find(1 + 5, `(${"1"} + 5)`) || find(1 * 3, `(${"1"} * 3)`);
```

The first operand will be attempted... So

---

Calling

```
find(1 + 5, `(${"1"} + 5)`)
```

Those variables are in memory stack #1:

- `current` is `6`
- `history` is `"(1 + 5)"`
- `target` is `13`

Makes:

```
find(6 + 5, `(${"(1 + 5)"} + 5)`) || find(6 * 3, `(${"(1 + 5)"} * 3)`);
```

---

Calling

```
find(6 + 5, `(${"(1 + 5)"} + 5)`)
```

Those variables are in memory stack #2:

- `current` is `11`
- `history` is `"((1 + 5) + 5)"`
- `target` is `13`

Makes:

```
find(11 + 5, `(${"((1 + 5) + 5)"} + 5)`) || find(11 * 3, `(${"((1 + 5) + 5)"} * 3)`);
```

---

Calling

```
find(11 + 5, `(${"((1 + 5) + 5)"} + 5)`)
```

Those variables are in memory stack #3:

- `current` is `16`
- `history` is `"(((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)"`
- `target` is `13`

It now hits the condition

```
else if (current > target) {
  return null;
}

// That is:
else if (16 > 13) {
  return null;
}
```

**Memory stack #3 is discarded** and memory stack #2 is popped, so the second operand will be evaluated:

- `current` is `11`
- `history` is `"((1 + 5) + 5)"`
- `target` is `13`

We now have:

```
null || find(11 * 3, `(${"((1 + 5) + 5)"} * 3)`);
```

Get it? We never attempted the second operand yet...
Continue doing it step by step like this and note down the variable values for each recursion step. When it returns, pop a stack and continue until it is all popped.

Also carefully note down who is the caller for each recursion step to know where the returned value goes.

Comment: ok, I did what you asked, step by step. So you are saying, that every time find result to null, the stack is discarded, so the one that pops the was executed before, get re executed with the old values stored in memory since it got its own scope. But then why doesn't blindly get re executed the left part of the || operator? how can it know it got to try the right part? In this case null || find(11 * 3, `(${"((1 + 5) + 5)"} * 3)`); yes, ok, but going back on the stack you reach one that executing the left operand doesn't give null anymore. How is doing that? Does it remember ?